# A Fiery Conversation

Tags: riddle, knowledge, affix-riddle

> **1st member:** It's too cold. Hey, can you [my prefix] some wood to endure this blizzard?
> **2nd member:** Of course.
>
> **FEW MOMENTS LATER**
>
> **2nd member:** There's a [my prefix]oon outside. Hey, can you check whether the gate has erosion?
> **3rd member:** Err... I'll do my best.
>
> **FEW MOMENTS LATER**
>
> **3rd member:** Now it's [my prefix]ng. Hey, can you check whether the thermometer is broken?
> **4th member:** Err, yes.
>
> **FEW MOMENTS LATER**
>
> **4th member:** I'd say it's [my prefix]al now. Hey, can you bring the video tape?
> **5th member:** Yes, though I'm unsure how that will help.
>
> **FEW MOMENTS LATER**
>
> **5th member:** Now it's down to [my prefix]ers. Hey, can you soar?
> **6th member:** Err, isn't that what only our 1st member can do?
>
> **FEW MOMENTS LATER**
>
> **6th member:** At least I can code in [my prefix]i. Hey, can you post this on Sandbox?
> **7th member:** Yeah.
>
> **FEW MOMENTS LATER**
>
> **7th member:** I can confirm we don't need an [my prefix]ator. Hey, watch me roar!
> **8th member:** This is why I'm waiting for a new member.

**Spell the names of all 8 members.**

Comment: @Ausername Err, no.

Comment: @Ausername It's not an esoteric language; it's practical.

Comment: I was thinking in the direction of rot13(qrycuv) @Ausername

Comment: @mrdeadsven I don't know how I didn't think of that, and it's kinda obvious what the name of #6 is now....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This puzzle conceals the names of:

> the **final evolutions of the fire-type starter Pokémon** in the first 8 generations of the [Pokémon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon) series of games.

In addition to the prefixes omitted from each line:

> each line also **ends with the suffix** of the Pokémon's name.

Like so:

> Gen 1: **[Charizard](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Charizard)** (*...can you **CHAR** some wood... bliz**ZARD***)
>  Gen 2: **[Typhlosion](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Typhlosion)** (*There's a **TYPH**oon outside... er**OSION***)
>  Gen 3: **[Blaziken](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Blaziken)** (*Now it's **BLAZI**ng... bro**KEN***)
>  Gen 4: **[Infernape](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Infernape)** (*...it's **INFERN**al now... t**APE***)
>  Gen 5: **[Emboar](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Emboar)** (*...it's down to **EMB**ers... s**OAR***)
>  Gen 6: **[Delphox](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Delphox)** (*...code in **DELPH**i... Sandb**OX***)
>  Gen 7: **[Incineroar](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Incineroar)** (*...need an **INCINER**ator... watch me **ROAR***)
>  Gen 8: **[Cinderace](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Cinderace)** (not encrypted in the puzzle, but inferred from the context)
>
>  [image: Fire starter Pokémon final evolutions, Gen 1 to 8]

This theme explains a couple of other things in the puzzle...

> (i) The title's mention of 'fiery' (these are **fire**-type Pokémon);
>
>  (ii) Why 'number 8' is waiting for 'a new member' - a ninth generation of Pokémon will follow one day...

<sub>*Credit where due: It was useful to have [confirmation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110829/a-fiery-conversation#comment311604_110830) that @mrdeadsven had correctly found the prefixes for #2 and #6.*</sub>

Comment: good find, though I'm 100% sure you would have had it without my answer :p

Comment: @mrdeadsven Perhaps eventually, but I was pretty fixated on MONSoon for a while before I spotted the OP's comment beneath your post. Once I realised the correct one there was only one thing in my mind! :)

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer/guesses, feel free to take mine into your own answers if you think you can use them :)

**1st member:** It's too cold. Hey, can you [my prefix] some wood to endure this blizzard?

**2nd member:** Of course.

> **Light**, this also because of the reference of soar to member 1 something that is light or lighter then something else.

**FEW MOMENTS LATER**

**2nd member:** There's a [my prefix]oon outside. Hey, can you check whether the gate has erosion?

**3rd member:** Err... I'll do my best.

> **Typh**oon, a typhoon would probably be a natural phenomenon in which erosion occurs

**FEW MOMENTS LATER**

**3rd member:** Now it's [my prefix]ng. Hey, can you check whether the thermometer is broken?

**4th member:** Err, yes.

> **freezi**ng, just seems the most logical as for checking the thermometer.

**FEW MOMENTS LATER**

**4th member:** I'd say it's [my prefix]al now. Hey, can you bring the video tape?

**5th member:** Yes, though I'm unsure how that will help.

> no clue I was thinking **norm**al, seems the most logical after the previous phenomenons that happened, but I can't place the video tape

**FEW MOMENTS LATER**

**5th member:** Now it's down to [my prefix]ers. Hey, can you soar?

**6th member:** Err, isn't that what only our 1st member can do?

> no clue

**FEW MOMENTS LATER**

**6th member:** At least I can code in [my prefix]i. Hey, can you post this on Sandbox?

**7th member:** Yeah.

> **Delph**i, coding language

**FEW MOMENTS LATER**

**7th member:** I can confirm we don't need an [my prefix]ator. Hey, watch me roar!

**8th member:** This is why I'm waiting for a new member.

> no clue

Comment: Err, you got only 2nd and 6th right. And the objective is to spell their **full** names, meaning that getting the prefixes isn't a full answer.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I know, I prefer to not post everything until I'm certain I have the complete answer with explanation while guessing I just write the bare minimum so other still have to do some guessing going from mine :)